# No video shown with RTCMTLVideoView in WebRTC iOS framework

Tags: ios, video, webrtc, video-streaming, metalkit

I am trying to integrate WebRTC Video into my iOS app. I downloaded the source code from https://webrtc.github.io/webrtc-org/native-code/ios/ and built it successfully. However, GLView is not supported in this codebase, so I had to use MetalKit and added RTCMTLVideoView to my class. I also added RTCVideoRenderer and RTCVideoViewDelegate and set self.metalVideoView.delegate = self.

When the method to handle incoming video is called, I can see that the object received from the notification is RTC_OBJC_TYPE(RTCMediaStreamTrack): video janusv0 enabled Live, and VideoTracks count is: 1. However, I am not able to see any video on the screen. Instead, I just see a blank screen. In the previous version of WebRTC, I used GLView with the same implementation and it worked fine.

Can you please review my implementation below and let me know if I am missing anything?

```
    @objc func handleFloorPlanVideoReceived(_ notification: Notification?) {
    if let remoteVideoTrack = notification?.object as? RTCVideoTrack {

        print("Recieved Remote Video: \(remoteVideoTrack)")

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Initialize the metalVideoView
            self.metalVideoView = RTCMTLVideoView(frame: CGRect.zero)
            self.metalVideoView.delegate = self

            // Add the metalVideoView to the view hierarchy
            self.view.addSubview(self.metalVideoView)
            self.metalVideoView.backgroundColor = .edgeGray
            self.metalVideoView.videoContentMode = .scaleAspectFit

            // Set up auto layout constraints
            self.metalVideoView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                self.metalVideoView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
                self.metalVideoView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
                self.metalVideoView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
                self.metalVideoView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1.0/3.0)
            ])

            remoteVideoTrack.add(self.metalVideoView)

            // Create and add the UIActivityIndicatorView
            let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .large)
            activityIndicator.color = .white
            self.metalVideoView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
            self.activityIndicator = activityIndicator

            // Set up constraints for the activity indicator
            activityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                activityIndicator.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.metalVideoView.centerXAnchor),
                activityIndicator.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.metalVideoView.centerYAnchor)
            ])

            activityIndicator.startAnimating()

            // Create and add the close button
            let closeButton = UIButton(type: .system)
            if let closeImage = UIImage(systemName: "xmark") {
                closeButton.setImage(closeImage, for: .normal)
            }

            self.metalVideoView.addSubview(closeButton)

            // Set up constraints for the close button
            closeButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                closeButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.metalVideoView.topAnchor, constant: 8),
                closeButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.metalVideoView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8)
            ])

            // Add target for close button tap event
            closeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.closeButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

            self.metalVideoView.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an issue. It was a typo on the server side. It says: "pachetization-mode-" instead of "packetization-mode=" in SDP. It worked with the old WebRTC Framework because it has default parameters and ignored that typo probably.